# How to resolve the errror: "The underlying connection was closed"?

Tags: iis-6

Does anyone know this problem:

> "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive."?

How can we resolve this problem?

Comment: Is there anything recorded in the event log or IIS logs?

Answer (score 1):

I have increased shutdown time in the application pool and now it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

yes, "the underlying connection was closed", or more precisely the browser was closed before the page loaded.

There's always the chance it's a real network level error (ie, bad proxy) but you don't provide enough detail.

Answer (score 0):

A Google search for "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive." throws [these](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=The%20underlying%20connection%20was%20closed:%20An%20unexpected%20error%20occurred%20on%20a%20receive.&gws_rd=ssl) results.

From there [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20201024035234/http://geekswithblogs.net/Denis/archive/2005/08/16/50365.aspx):

> ...I have added the following code to
> my reference.cs file (which needs to
> be done each time I update the
> webservice reference) to assign the
> keepalive value to false to allow the
> connection to be closed and reopened.
>
> ```
> protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
>         {
>             HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(uri);
>
>             webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
>             webRequest.ProtocolVersion=HttpVersion.Version10;
>             return webRequest;
>         }
>
>
> I have also added a reference to System.Net via a using statement to
> ```
>
> import the HttpWebRequest namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic error that can be caused by just about anything (In my case some tiff images were causing gdi+ error in a wcf service).

Start by checking:

1. IIS log files
2. Application log files (ie. enable service logging if you use services)
3. Permissions and security